# Extending a function from a contractible open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, algebraic-topology

Consider a contractible open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $V\subset U$ is also contractible (open set). Consider a continuous function $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that we can always extend $f$ to a continuous function $h:U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h|_V=f$?

**Edit:** The answers/comments suggests that it is not true in general. Can we impose some conditions on $f$ which will facilitate such an extension?

Comment: Presumably you want $h$ to be continuous? Otherwise, just define it anyway you want outside of $V$...

Comment: Yes. I want $h$ to be continuous.

Comment: Then *say so*, in the post. The government really hates it when I read minds without a warrant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you know what "uniform continuity" means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original question has already been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $U = \mathbb R$, $V = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: Will it help if I take $f$ to be a bounded function?

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee Take $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can we impose any condition of $f$ which will make the extension possible?